# Implementing IAppBuilder for non HTTP based middleware pipeline

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-2.2

I'd like to build a middleware-based pipeline that has nothing to do with ASP.NET core or HTTP (think Extract, Transform, and Load pipeline for building a data warehouse).  This is presently done in a self-hosted application with `IHostBuilder`  There are many steps in this type of solution so the pattern of being able to plug in middleware into the pipeline like ASP.NET Core does is very appealing.  I thought I would start by creating my own pipeline builder interface based on `IAppBuilder` in .NET Core which is listed below.

```
public interface IEtlPipelineBuilder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the service provider that provides access to the ETL engines service container.
    /// </summary>
    IServiceProvider PipelineServices { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the set of ETL features the engine provides.
    /// </summary>
    //IFeatureCollection ServerFeatures { get; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a key/value collection that can be used to share data between middleware.
    /// </summary>
    IDictionary<string, object> Properties { get; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a middleware delegate to the ETL pipeline.
    /// </summary>
    IEtlPipelineBuilder Use(Func<JobDelegate, JobDelegate> middleware);
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new  instance of a pipeline builder that shares the properties of this IEtlPipelineBuilder
    /// </summary>
    IEtlPipelineBuilder New();
    /// <summary>
    /// Builds the delegate used by this application to process ETL job requests.
    /// </summary>
    JobDelegate Build();
}
```

Now I need to implement this which is where my question starts.

1. Is there already an implementation that I could use for building a middleware-based pipeline of my own that has nothing to do with HTTP?
2. Can anyone think of any downsides to implementing my own builder?

Only thing I can think of related to question 3 is maybe not being able to leverage other extensions that are based on an OWIN pipeline, but please feel free to provide others.

Comment: I would forget anything to do with HTTP. You probably want to look at something like Chain Of Responsibility pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) or even a Strategy Pattern and modify it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I after reading that, it seems as though this is the pattern that the ASP.NET Core team used to implement middleware within the Http pipeline. They seem to be offering non-http services and classes to help with non-http hosts just as mine (Generic Host) and the implementation of this pattern using services and middleware seems really intuitive so I wondered if maybe there were other non-http based classes that I could leverage instead of implementing the entire IAppBuilder type code.